# Visual Studio 2017 Theme Issues

Tags: color-theme, visual-studio-2017

I'm not sure how this happened but my text editor box is light themed while the rest of the application is dark themed.  I have tried resetting the theme, restarting my computer, going through each theme, and nothing has worked.  Has anyone ran into this issue? How did they reset their themes to default? I am trying to get back to the default dark theme.
[image]

Comment: Delete the preference folder for Visual Studio

Comment: Go to Tools>Options and click>Fonts and Colors 
Select Text Editor from the first dropdown and specify its background from the Item Background dropdown.

Comment: That's the problem, the default dark grey is no longer there, there is black, but it looks very odd and hard to read

Answer (score 1):

Tools -> Options
   General -> Fonts and colors.

You should be able to revert the colors back to "default" here.

Comment: That's the issue, the dark themed default colors no longer show up.  I am not sure what happened to them.